# In Android xml use String array value

Tags: android, xml

How I can use Android string array in xml for Initialization
I want get Email:  text of array

```
 <string-array name="detalis">
    <item >Wanted</item>
    <item >Company:</item>
    <item >Event</item>
    <item >Vacancy:</item>
    <item >Position:</item>
    <item >Race:</item>
    <item >Gender:</item>
    <item >Age:</item>
    <item >Jobscope:</item>
    <item >Venue:</item>
    <item >Date:</item>
    <item >Time:</item>
    <item >Break:</item>
    <item >Pay: </item>
    <item >Uniform:</item>
    <item >Transport: </item>
    <item >Standby area:</item>
    <item >Food:</item>
    <item >Interview:</item>
    <item >Requirements:</item>
    <item >Training:</item>
    <item >Client:</item>
    <item >Foreigners:</item>
    <item >Clients Contact:</item>
    <item >Phone: </item>
    <item >Email:</item>
    <item >Subject:</item>
</string-array>
```

I do that,but error

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:text="@array/detalis"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="15sp" />`
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible to reference an individual string from an array. One work around would be to separate the array into strings and then build the array from those strings.

```
<string name="details_email">Email:</string>
<string name="details_subject">Subject:</string>

<string-array name="details">
    <item >@string/details_email</item>
    <item >@string/details_subject</item>
</string-array>`
```

That way you can still have your array and reference individual strings